# How to draw on Windows Phone like on HTML canvas

Tags: windows-phone-7, draw

I want to draw on Windows Phone 7 (Xna or whatever) like I draw on a HTML canvas, Processing or Java Graphics. Is it possible?

I found an answer that say to use the WriteableBitmap class, but how can I use it?

What I want is to draw in a raster image with functions like fillRect, fillOval, drawImage, etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "draw"? You mean let your users draw? Or you have an image that you want to draw? Please explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7MultiTouchDrawing-4513213a) for you. This shows exactly how to simulate a touch based drawing canvas.  Hope this helps you in your endeavor :)

**Edit:** Tutorial #2

[Another tutorial](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=137) to help you with the same.

Comment: Why I need to make a `new Line()`? This line will be stored as a vector shape?

Comment: @Guerreiro: You need new Line() because those each pixels are stored together as a single line.

Comment: Did the tutorials help you?